# python setup.py install and module not found error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm building my own PyTorch CUDA extension and trying to get it to install in a Docker container. In this case the code compiles (and is actually being generated by a code generator) when the container is started on a compute cluster.

Due to the way execution on the cluster works, I can run one script as root before my own application script is launched. This script doesn't have access to the python extension's code as the code is dynamically generated by a code generator. For this reason, I do the following to allow my job to install packages (the python interpreter in the container is in /opt/conda/bin):

```
chmod 777 /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages
```

My PyTorch extension is then built using the permissions of the user launching the container. At that point a script simply runs the following in the output folder of the code generator:

```
python setup.py install
```

The code is built just fine and I see the following directory being created:

```
/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/foobar-1.2.4-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg
```

The following code then works inside the container:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/foobar-1.2.4-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg")
import foobar
```

However, if I drop the sys.path.insert, I get:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'foobar'
```

It seems like an egg file in site-packages isn't automatically discoverable? The contents of the folder is:

```
/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/foobar-1.2.4-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/__pycache__
/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/foobar-1.2.4-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/__pycache__/foobar.cpython-36.pyc
/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/foobar-1.2.4-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/foobar.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/foobar-1.2.4-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/foobar.py
/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/foobar-1.2.4-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/EGG-INFO
/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/foobar-1.2.4-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/EGG-INFO/SOURCES.txt
/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/foobar-1.2.4-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/EGG-INFO/top_level.txt
/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/foobar-1.2.4-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/EGG-INFO/dependency_links.txt
/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/foobar-1.2.4-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/EGG-INFO/not-zip-safe
/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/foobar-1.2.4-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/EGG-INFO/native_libs.txt
/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/foobar-1.2.4-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/EGG-INFO/PKG-INFO
```

I see that some packages have pth-files under site-packages, but none is being generated by `python setup.py install`. I do see in the logs of running setup.py the following:

```
removing 'build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg' (and everything under it)
Processing foobar-1.2.4-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg
creating /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/foobar-1.2.4-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg
Extracting foobar-1.2.4-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg to /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Adding foobar 1.2.4 to easy-install.pth file
```

However, I don't actually see any pth file being created. Any ideas how to  make the package visible? There are no permission denied errors either and chmodding the whole site-packages folder to be recursively world writable doesn't solve the problem either.

EDIT: One interesting thing to note is that I can't find a file named "easy-install.pth" anywhere inside the docker image. Should such a file exist in the site-packages? These are the only pth files:

```
root@cb54e4e35141:/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages# ls *.pth
matplotlib-3.1.1-py3.6-nspkg.pth               sphinxcontrib_htmlhelp-1.0.2-py3.7-nspkg.pth
protobuf-3.8.0-py3.6-nspkg.pth                 sphinxcontrib_jsmath-1.0.1-py3.7-nspkg.pth
pytest-cov.pth                                 sphinxcontrib_qthelp-1.0.2-py3.7-nspkg.pth
sphinxcontrib_applehelp-1.0.1-py3.7-nspkg.pth  sphinxcontrib_serializinghtml-1.1.3-py3.7-nspkg.pth
sphinxcontrib_devhelp-1.0.1-py3.7-nspkg.pth
```

UPDATE: Turns out that `pip install .` instead of `python setup.py install` solves the problem...

Comment: I'm having the same problem but pip install . throws an error about how install needs at leas one parameter. I tried pip3 install . but that only creates the egg file and the app can't be imported. Is there another solution for this?